# ToolTip inside a page within frame

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I need to use the **ToolTip** on a label inside a *xaml*

```
<Page x:Class="xxx.xxx"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
          mc:Ignorable="d" 
          d:DesignHeight="464" d:DesignWidth="628"
        Title="ManagementDetails" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

        <Grid>  
            <Label Margin="0,360,376,91" >
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                      <ToolTip Content="Turtle" />         
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Label> 
         </Grid>
    </Page>
```

this *xaml* file is used to be a child inside a **frame** contained in another *xaml* file

```
<Window x:Class="xxx.xxxxxx"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ViewProject" Height="626" Width="810" >
    <Grid  Height="600" Width="800">
        <Frame Margin="172,136,0,0" Name="frame1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

i embedded the *page xaml* file inside the **frame** using

```
 MyClass myClass= new MyClass();
frame1.Navigate(myClass);
```

if i moved the **label** with the **ToolTip** from the *page xaml* file to the *window xaml* file the **ToolTip** work but when use it inside the *page xaml* file it doesn't work.

what is missing here to make it work inside the page xaml file

Comment: I tried the code from question in a sample app, and it works fine. I am using VS2013 Ultimate, but the project was targeted to .net framework 4.

Comment: You tried to make two XAML files one Window and the other Page , the window contains a Frame anf you embedded the Page inside the frame , then applied the ToolTip on a control in the page xaml file and it worked ?!

Comment: Yep, I have two XAML files (1, MainWindow.xaml, with a frame and a Page1.xaml). In Loaded event handler of MainWindow, I am loading Page1 into frame by doing frame1.Navigate(new Page1()); and I see ToolTip

Comment: would you please post the code of the frame tag ,, and full code of the page xaml file

Comment: Frame Tag Code: `    <Grid  Background="Gray">
        <Frame Margin="30" Name="frame1" />
    </Grid>
`

Comment: Page1.XAML `<Page x:Class="WpfApplication2.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
 Title="Page1"
      Background="Green">
    <Grid>
        <Label>
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Content="Turtle" />
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Page>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all your answers it seems that is was my fault and feel ashamed, i had duplicate xaml files for the same page and i was editing one and viewing another one. Sorry for this inconvenience and thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it this way?!?

Just do something like:

```
<Label Name="Some_Label" ToolTip="Turtle"> Fun with labels ...</Label>
```

Done. Should work inside another or by itself.

Comment: this also only works just fine for any control inside a window not inside a Page embedded in a Frame

Answer (score 0):

**Using the ToolTip Control:**

The `ToolTipService` class must be used along with the `ToolTip` control in order to display a tooltip to our control.  For the example I will use an image control, but the following can be applied to each of the controls. Here is the code:

```
 <Image Source="GiantSeaTurtle.jpg" Width="400" Height="300">
      <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="Turtle"></ToolTip>
      </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Image>
```

Comment: Sorry but it seems that you didn't read my question well , i already did what you have said and the ToolTip works with me fine my problem only when i use the ToolTip on a control inside a Page embedded inside a frame.